# Android (Studio) FileNotFoundException but File is on SD card

Tags: android, android-studio, filenotfoundexception, file-exists

So for sometime now ive been trying to implement joanzapata's pdfview, from:
"http://joanzapata.com/android-pdfview/"

The main focus is for this to be API-10+ Friendly.

No matter what I do I keep getting one error or another, somehow now I have the project working (apparently) but when I find my PDF file and try and load it with the same code as the projects Sample, I get the following issue.

Firstly my code:

```
...
//File currentLoc = new File(string_pdfLoc);
...
//File thePdf  = currentLoc;
//thePdf is of type File
    if( thePdf != null ) {
        Log.d("MyDebug", "1/3 File not Null");
        if( thePdf.exists() ) {
            Log.d("MyDebug", "2/3 File exists");
            if (thePdf.canRead()) {
                Log.d("MyDebug", "3/3 File can be Read");
                Log.d("MyDebug", "thePDF: " + thePdf.getAbsolutePath());

                //------ PDF should Exist ----------------------
                Log.d("MyDebug","Should now load thePDFView");
                //pdfView.fromAsset(pdfName)
                Log.d("MyDebug","thePDFView.fromAsset");
                thePDFView.fromAsset(thePdf.getAbsolutePath() );
                Log.d("MyDebug","thePDFView.fromAsset.load");
                thePDFView.fromAsset(thePdf.getAbsolutePath() ).load();

            } else {
                Log.d("MyDebug", "File exists, but cannot Read");
            }
        }else{
            Log.d("MyDebug", "File != null, but !exists");
        }
    }else{
        Log.d("MyDebug","thePDF, is still null");
    }
```

---

And now the error, take note that "company" & "projectname" are normally named differently but still lower-case charcters, but I have hidden their name.

```
Found a PDF File
D/MyDebug? 1/3 File not Null
D/MyDebug? 2/3 File exists
D/MyDebug? 3/3 File can be Read
D/MyDebug? thePDF: /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.projectname.company.projectname/files/ThisisaPDF.pdf
D/MyDebug? Should now load thePDFView
D/MyDebug? thePDFView.fromAsset
D/AndroidRuntime? Shutting down VM
W/dalvikvm? threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41942da0)
E/AndroidRuntime? FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.projectname.company.projectname, PID: 9591
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.projectname.tpub.projectname/com.projectname.company.projectname.PdfViewActivity}: com.joanzapata.pdfview.exception.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.projectname.company.projectname/files/ThisisaPDF.pdf does not exist.
...
 Caused by: com.joanzapata.pdfview.exception.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.projectname.company.projectname/files/ThisisaPDF.pdf does not exist.
        at com.joanzapata.pdfview.PDFView.fromAsset(PDFView.java:905)
        at     com.projectname.company.projectname.PdfViewActivity.onCreate(PdfViewActivity.java:88)
```

---

Here is the permission I have in the Manifest:

```
<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
    />
```

Here is my Gradle(app).Build file:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.3'
    compile 'com.joanzapata.pdfview:android-pdfview:1.0.+@aar'
}
```

---

So as far as I can tell, the Plugin should be being brought in, otherwise I would expect some errors such as the ones I have had in the past regarding Gradle.

Any advice is most welcome, I will be checking this often, any suggestions I can easily try and respond.

Answer (score 1):

Based on my reading of [the source code](https://github.com/JoanZapata/android-pdfview/blob/master/android-pdfview/src/main/java/com/joanzapata/pdfview/PDFView.java), `fromAsset()` is for reading in an asset. Try `fromFile()` instead.

Comment: I tried that (fromFile) in a few different ways and I got some form of a NoSuchField exception (double check name tonight). I read yesterday it maybe due to different compile versions going together. When I make a build, I always Clean first then run Gradle.Build, is this right as I edit my menu activity layout to hard show the date and time and that updates fine.

Comment: Re-ran the code, I get the Exception:
NoSuchFieldError
From at com.twisteddark.tpub.twisteddark.PdfViewActivity.onCreate(PdfViewActivity.java:93) and the associated load() method.

Comment: @Yin117: You will need to either ask a fresh Stack Overflow question, with your modified code and a complete stack trace, or talk to the developers of the library.

Comment: Ok Shall do that tonight.